# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'

Tags: python, numpy, import, matplotlib, attributeerror

I think I'm having troubles importing pylab. A similar error occurs when I import numpy.
Here is my code

```
from math import radians, sin, cos
from pylab import plot, xlabel, ylabel, title, show

v0=input("Enter v0 (m/s)...")
alpha0=input("enter alpha0 (degrees)...")
g=input("Enter g (m/s^2)..")

radalpha0=radians(alpha0)
t_inc=0.01
t=0
i=0
x=[]
y=[]

x.append(v0*cos(radalpha0)*t)
y.append(v0*sin(radalpha0)*t-0.5*g*t*t)

while y[i]>=0:
    i=i+1
    t=t+t_inc
    x.append(v0*cos(radalpha0)*t)
    y.append(v0*sin(radalpha0)*t-0.5*g*t*t)

xlabel('x')
ylabel('x')
plot(x,y)
title('Motion in two dimensions')
show()
```

I get this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2d_motion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pylab import plot, xlabel, ylabel, title, show
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyparsing import Literal, ZeroOrMore, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 109, in <module>
    alphas = string.lowercase + string.uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'
```

Is there any problem with the syntax?

I'm using python2.7 on fedora18.

Comment: By the way I'm having same output when I write 
   from pylab import *
in the python console

Comment: What do you get if you type `import string` and then `print string.__file__` at the console?

Comment: I get the line;
string.pyc

Comment: That's all it says?  Not `'/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'`?  Then it looks like you somehow wound up with a different module named `string` in the directory, and that's the one being imported instead.  Delete `string.pyc` and try again (also check to make sure there's no file called `string.py` in your directory.)

Comment: Well it works! So I must be careful with naming modules.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

2020 addendum: Note `string.lowercase` was for Python 2 only.

In Python 3, use `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of `string.lowercase`

```
Python 3.6.8 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
>>> import string
>>> string.lowercase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'lowercase'
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 7):

After some discussion in the comments, it turned out (as it usually does when builtin modules suddenly seem to give `AttributeErrors`) that the problem was that another module named `string` was shadowing the builtin one.

One way to check this is to look at the `__file__` attribute of the module, or just look at the `repr` itself:

```
>>> print string
<module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>
```

if the `from` doesn't point to the right place, you've got the wrong module being read.

Solution: delete/rename the offending `string.py`/`string.pyc` files.

Comment: I got the same issue and your answer helped me. However, I find it a bit unsatisfying. Being not allowed to give common names like `string` to any *sub*modules seems like quite a strong and uncomfortable restriction.